# Integral of a rational function

Tags: calculus, integration

$$
 \int \frac{\sqrt[3]{x}+1}{\sqrt[4]{x^3}(\sqrt{x} - \sqrt[6]{x})dx}
$$

So I used substitution method:
$$
x = t^{12}
$$
$$
dx = 12t^{11}dt
$$
and I ended up with a very weird integral... 
could you help me?

Comment: Maybe it is better to put $dx$ in the numerator?

Comment: What weird integral?

Comment: The problem is, that dx is in the denominator and I think I can't touch it.

Comment: With $dx$ in the denominator, the rest of us do not know what that notation means, so you will have to supply a definition.

Comment: @GEdgar reminds me of [an old joke](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/304557/7933). :) I moved the $dx$ out of the denominator.

Comment: @TomDavies92 The integral doesn't mean anything with the $dx$ in the denominator. $dx$ is not a number that can be plugged into any formula, it is notation. If the problem really has $dx$ in the deonominator, then the problem is unanswerable because the notation is meaningless.

Comment: (But I reverted my edit since you insist that the $dx$ has to be in the denominator.) Either that was a typo in your homework, or the creator of the problem is having some fun at your expense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, this is beautiful.  When you substitute $x=t^{12}$, you get

$$12 \int dt \frac{t^4-1}{t^4+1}$$

Use partial fractions to show that

$$\frac{t^4-1}{t^4+1} = 1 + \frac{1/2}{t+1} - \frac{1/2}{t-1} + \frac{1}{1+t^2}$$

Then the integral is

$$12 t + 6 \log{\left (\frac{t+1}{t-1}\right)} + 12 \arctan{t} + C$$

where $C$ is an integration constant.  Substitute back $t=x^{1/12}$ and you are done.

Comment: Thank you !:) Now I see it. It seems you just moved dx in the numerator and then substituted. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes.  The $dx$ in the denominator is nonsensical.