# In integral, would it make any sense to write dx as denominator?

Tags: integration

Does it make any sense to write something like this?

$$ \int \frac 1{dx} $$

I ***think*** I saw it somewhere, but since I can not find anything similar on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral) and [wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Integral.html), I have to assume that this is actually nonsese. So is it?

Closest thing found was $ \int f(x) d \alpha(x) $,

but it is not the same as $ \int f(x) \alpha(dx) $.

Comment: May be you can interpret it as $\int \frac{dy}{dx} dy$. If this is independent from $y$.

Comment: Perhaps you saw $$\int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}$$ instead?

Comment: Maybe $\frac{1}{\mathrm{d}x}=\infty$.

Comment: After some thought (and deleting my previous comment) I think @Eclipse Sun is right. As the $dx$ gets really small, $\frac{1}{dx}$ goes off to infinity. So you get an infinite sum of terms, each infinite. So I don't think there's much use there.

Comment: It represent a hipernatural infinite number. In any case it seems that integral diverge or is not defined.

Comment: Old joke about this expression: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/304557/7933

Comment: @EclipseSun what if the numerator is not 1?

Comment: So I understand now that it is meaningless. Thanks.