# What's this : $\displaystyle\int{\frac{1}{{x}dx}}$ equal if it is a correct formula?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I'm confused if it is possible to evaluate this class of integral if it is a correct formula :

> **QUESTION:**
>
> What's this : $\displaystyle\int{\frac{1}{{x}dx}}$ equal if it is a correct formula ?

Comment: Do you really mean $\int \frac 1{x\,\mathrm{d}x}$, or rather $\int \frac 1{x}\mathrm{d}x$?

Comment: yes, i seek if this suitable formula with measure theory and if it is how i can evaluate it

Comment: The notation $\int \frac{1}{x\,dx}$ is nonsense.

Comment: $\frac 1{\mathrm{d} x}$ does not correspond to a measure, e.g. additivity is violated.

Comment: @MarkViola Actually, it is not. Unusual, but it can be made make perfect sense including being a particular case of a very common notation.

Comment: In that case it would be helpful to know where you encountered this integral. Even if it could be interpreted in a meaningful way, it might still be just a typo.

Comment: It is meaningless. See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304549/how-to-evaluate-a-definite-integral-that-involves-dx2/304557#304557

Comment: @NinaSimone "Unusual, but it can be made make perfect sense including being a particular case of a very common notation" I am surprised. Would you care to provide some more explanations?

Comment: @NinaSimone Oh?  Please educate us on this "unusual" notation.

Comment: It is *not* correct notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would be surprised if it was a correct formula. If there was, it would at least not be the standard way to write integrals. In the notation of an integral, the $dx$ part is reminiscent of the fact that the integral stems from a summation
$$
\int f(x) dx \approx \sum_{i} f(x_{i}) \Delta x_{i}
$$
where $\Delta x_{i} \rightarrow 0$. So I would say - without knowing further context - that the formula is a typo and that the person who wrote it did unintentionally put the $dx$ under the fraction line.

What is probably meant is
$$
\int \frac{1}{x} dx,
$$
which is a standard integral with stem function $\ln(x)$.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

In order for the notation $\int f(x)\frac 1{\mathrm{d} x}$ to make sense, the map $A\mapsto \int_A\frac 1{\mathrm{d} x}$ would have to be a measure on $\mathbb R$ (where $A\subset \mathbb R$ measurable).

But an expression of the form "1 over Lebesgue measure" will not be a measure any more, it violates additivity, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Almost surely, there is a serious typo in the expression that motivates the question. That is, an expression $\int_X {f(x)\over g(x)\,dx}$ does not have any clear interpretation in contemporary mathematics, ... other than as a typo for $\int_X {f(x)\over g(x)}\;dx$. After all, the $\int_X...dx$ is really just a historical artifact for a linear functional, perhaps extended by continuity from $C^o_c(X)$ to a larger class of functions.