# Find the integral $\int \frac{1}{dx}$

Tags: integration

I was given a task and it seems this is not a joke. I am shocked and do not even know where to start ...

$$\int \frac{1}{dx}=???$$

Comment: Maybe they want the integral of $\frac1x$?

Comment: It's trivial....  log|x| +C

Comment: This is a long shot that only suits if it's meant to be a trick question, but if whoever set it thinks $\int f(x)$ is an acceptable abbreviation for $\int f(x)dx$, it could mean $\int\frac{1}{cx}=\frac1c\ln|x|+C$ with $c=d$ (where $C$ is locally constant, possibly taking different values for $x>0,\,x<0$).

Comment: *Who* gave the task and where is this from? This may make sense if one is talking about $f(t)=\frac{1}{d\cdot x}$ where $d$ and $x$ are two constants, so $\int f(t)\,dt=\frac{t}{dx}+C$... If it is a joke, then it is a really bad one.

Comment: @J.G. Or maybe it was just $$\int \frac{1}{dx}dd=\frac1x\ln|d|+c$$ Who knows that? :)

Comment: [In integral, would it make any sense to write dx as denominator?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1371183/9464)

Comment: Also: [What's this : $\displaystyle\int{\frac{1}{{x}dx}}$ equal if it is a correct formula?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2371728/9464)

Comment: The joke [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/304557/505767).

Comment: this question is hilarious though

Answer (score 4):

In calculus context, that expression

$$\color{red}{\int \frac{1}{dx}}$$

in **completely meaningless** indeed the symbol $dx$ we use in the integrals is just a symbol to indicate the variable we are considering for integration. We can't manage it as a number.

Comment: $dx$ is not _just_ that. Depending on your field, of course. In calculus it is just that, but in both measure theory and differential geometry it has a very specific meaning. At any rate, $\int\frac1{dx}$ is still meaningless.

Comment: @Arthur You are right, I need to specify that. Thanks

Comment: since you dont need an dx in an Integral you just read it as d*x with the constant d and have as an result 1/d*ln(x)+C

Comment: @trula That's a also a possibility! But what a bad choice for symbols!

Comment: @gimusi :-) nice last comment.